# socket program is able to connect to the port which is still in TIME_WAIT

Tags: php-socket

1. I have written a very simple socket server.
2. It listens in post 63254.
3. First i did a socket_create, socket_bind, socket_listen so here a connection is listening.
4. Then in a loop i do the socket accpet. so here another listen.
5. the read function reads untill i input exit.
6. after that the resource id  by socket_accept closes.
7. and then the main connection closes.

when i checked this process in TCPview after closing all connections i can still see the system process showing TIME_WAIT for post 63254

if i again run the socket server program it is connecting and when one full process is over all the connection is closed and the program terminated and now i can see another TIME_WAIT for the same port. but still i could connect to the same port the third time.

in stackover question answer it is said that connection cannot be done for port which is in wait state.

I opened firefox browser it opened 4 connections.
when i closed it all closed and the system process showed 4 time waits for 2 minutes.
all time wait stays for 2 minutes and disappears.

so what i conclude is for every connection close the time wait is occurs and cannot be avoided.

i read many posts in stack overflow flow but still wasn't sure of it.

*i run the following code in command line.*

**My server Code**

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(); 

$str = '';
$buff = '';

$s = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if(!$s)die('Unable to create socket');

if(!socket_bind($s,'127.0.0.1',63254))
    die("\nTrying to Bind: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));

if(!socket_listen($s,1))
    die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));

    while(1)
    {
        $acc = socket_accept($s);
        if(!$acc)die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
//      echo "\n".gettype($acc);
        if(!$acc)die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));

        while(1)
        {
            $str = socket_read($acc,512);
            $buff.= $str;
            echo $str;
//          echo '::'.gettype($str);

            if($str===false)die(socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
            if($str=="exit\r\n")break;          
        }

//      if(!socket_shutdown($acc,2))echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());  
        socket_close($acc);     
        if(preg_match('/exit/',$buff))break;
    }
//echo "\nConnection closed by server\n";   
//if(!socket_shutdown($s,2))echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
socket_close($s);
?>
```

**The client code**

```
<?
    set_time_limit(0);
    $f = fsockopen('127.0.0.1',63254,$a,$b,10);
    if(!$f)die('cannot connect');
    echo "\nConnected: \n";
    do{
        $buff = fgets(STDIN);   
        fwrite($f,$buff);
    }while($buff!="exit\r\n");
    fclose($f);
?>
```

need suggestions to improve a better client server if this is not sufficient. this code is just a child's play. just trying to understand the way communication works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In stackover question answer it is
>   said that connection cannot be done
>   for port which is in wait state.

I don't know what answer you're referring to, but you cannot *bind* to a port which is in TIME_WAIT state. If you are a server you can use setReuseAddress() to overcome this. If you're a client you have to wait, or use a different outbound port, or best of all don't specify an outbound port at all, let the system find one. You are a server so this doesn't apply to you.

> I opened firefox browser it opened 4
>   connections. when i closed it all
>   closed and the system process showed 4
>   time waits for 2 minutes. all time
>   wait stays for 2 minutes and
>   disappears.

But those are client ports. Outbound ports. At your server they were inbound ports, and there was also a listening port on the same port number. As long as there is a listening port, an inbound connnection can succeed.

> so what i conclude is for every
>   connection close the time wait is
>   occurs and cannot be avoided.

TIME_WAIT occurs when you are the end that *sends* the close first. If you are the end that *received* the close, and closed in response, your port doesn't go into TIME_WAIT at all.

Comment: oh. a lot of information i have got. i need to process your answer. need some time. besides. the above code exits properly and i can see one time wait for 2 mins. Is that normal. the first code is the server and the second one is the client. I did not know that i have caught a big fish.

Comment: I told you what is normal. I don't know what fish have to do with it.

Comment: ah. big fish means i have got a lot to work with and i have got a lot of information form you. big fish = more than expected information.

Comment: so, according to your last para i need my code not to enter into a time wait. could you suggest what is missing in my code? and still i can see many time waits in TCPView. does that mean that programs like firefox are letting the time wait occur?

Comment: since the information is new for me to analyse i posted the same question in codeproject (http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3621673/socket-program-is-able-to-connect-to-the-port-whic.aspx) and got a response which was clear. and i am analyzing this answer and checking with the documentation and meanwhile i found that what EJP said was correct but i need to still understand many concepts in his response. meanwhile i am waiting for some more days for others to give in their suggestions. just expecting as stated by stack overflow tips for getting an answer. hasta luego.

Comment: Answer to what? You've had the correct answer. You don't even have a problem. The system is working as designed.